# Javascript: how to copy reference properly?

Tags: javascript

I have array and two variables. These variables are meant to hold references to array items, in fact, to select new object and hold previously selected. This code makes selectedObject and prevselectedObject to be the same :(

```
if(newSelection)
{
    if(this.prevselectedObject != newSelection)
    {
        this.prevselectedObject = this.selectedObject;
    }

    this.selectedObject = newSelection;
}
else
{
    this.prevselectedObject = this.selectedObject;
    this.selectedObject = null;
}
```

Guess, this.prevselectedObject = this.selectedObject; actually puts in prevselectedObject variable reference to selectedObject. But I want to copy reference that is in selectedObject to prevselectedObject. There are dirty hacks for copy-by-value if value is string or int, but what to do with references?

Comment: I've really not sure what the problem is. It might help if you provided a complete [test case](http://sscce.org/) and describes what output you wanted and how that differed from what you got.

Comment: myArray.slice(0); usually create a clone of the content. I didn't try, but can it help?

Comment: .slice(0) creates a one deep copy, if you want a truly deep copy, there's nothing built in to JavaScript, so just loop and recursively copy. I'd guess various frameworks (jQuery, etc.) provide deep copying, so if you're using one of those already, investigate whether it does or not. I don't think I'd use a framework just for this though, it's a fairly straightforward recursive function.

Comment: `this.prevselectedObject = this.selectedObject` just makes `prevselectedObject` point to the same value that `selectedObject` references. What is exactly you issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like it could work, then I decided to put it into the answer.YOu can use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var clone = myArray.slice(0);
```

Or even more interesting:

```
Array.prototype.clone = function() {
    return this.slice(0);
};
```

and after this use it as a clone function for any array.

Hope it helps.

Comment: As I noted in my comment to the original question, .slice(0) just makes a one-deep copy. If your array is all ints or strings for example, that's fine, but if it can contain other arrays or objects, then those subarrays and subobjects will be shared, which may or may not be what you want. I certainly wouldn't call a prototype function which just does a one level deep copy clone, because prototype functions should work on all instances of that type, and I would expect a clone function to make a complete (deep) copy.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I gave an answer for the particular question (or how I understood this question). Also author mention "There are dirty hacks for copy-by-value"... which he didn't want... But for sure - your point is true